# How to create donation software?

Tags: security, web-design

I have a requirement to create a donation software for a project.

Does anyone know how KickStarter designed theirs? What are the security elements involved? How do I create the credit card transactions-processing part? Is there some common library/service used for that?

I am still in research phases for this, so any ideas appreciated!

Comment: There is also kiva.org and http://www.vittana.org I would check them out at least for the UI ideas. Not sure how they work under the hood, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a lot of issues for handling credit cards.  The easiest solution is using a service like Paypal's service to process the credit cards.  That way, all you have to do is store the amount and a PayPal Transaction ID.

You can then start moving up to more complicated solutions, directly using gateways such as Verisign (yes, that's part of PayPal) or Authorize.net or any of a lot more.

Things that you will need to think about, especially if you start to go towards using merchant account APIs

- PCI Compliance
- Fraud protection
- Dispute handling
- Auditing
- Getting an Internet Merchant Account
- Storing/ Not storing/ encrypting personal identifiable information

It's a really broad topic, and there are a lot of answers out there.  This is a bit of a start of things you'll have to think about.

Comment: PayPal even might wave some fees, as it did for some other big charities.

Comment: Good advice. The "real" credit card companies (quite rightly) make you jump through several technical, legal and procedural hoops before they will allow you to connect.